# Adding second variable in foreach command - Stata

Tags: foreach, stata

I have datasets like this:

```
C:\temp\SalesFigures FY13.dta
C:\temp\SalesFigures FY14.dta
C:\temp\SalesFigures FY15.dta
etc.
```

Each file contains sales data from 50 states. I often need to run a block of code for just some of the states in these files. I specify those states in a file called `StatesToRun.dta` (e.g., AK, CA, WA) and use a `foreach` command to loop through each state. I also use a macro to specify the FY .dta file I want to use.

For example:

```
* Specify file to run. 
local FY "FY14"

* Run code only for the states I list in StatesToRun.dta.
use "C:/temp/StatesToRun.dta", clear
levelsof state, local(statelist)

foreach MyState of local statelist 

{

use "C:/temp/SalesFigures 'FY'.dta", clear
keep if state == `"`MyState'"' 
* etc. ...

}
```

**THE NEED**

I sometimes need to run my code for several of the FY files in `C:\temp`. So I'd like to create a loop for that, too. For example, if I wanted to run the code for AK, CA, and WA, for the FY14 and FY15 .dta files, I'd enter "AK", "CA", and "WA" for state in `StatesToRun.dta`, and "FY14" and "FY15" for a variable I could call "FY" in `StatesToRun.dta`. I'm just not sure how to incorporate this second variable into the loop. I read you can nest `foreach` statements, but I'm not sure if that's the best approach.

Being rather new to Stata, this is my best guess:

```
* Run code only for the states and FYs I list in StatesToRun.dta.
use "C:/temp/StatesToRun.dta", clear
levelsof state, local(statelist)
levelsof FY, local(FYlist)

foreach MyState of local statelist {
foreach MyFY of local FYlist {

use "C:/temp/SalesFigures 'MyFY'.dta", clear
keep if state == `"`MyState'"' 
* etc. ...

}
}
```

Am I on the right path?

Comment: The first example won't run; the open curly brace must be on the same line as the `foreach`.

Comment: It seems needlessly indirect to put e.g. `AK CA WA` in a dataset just to take them out again. Why not type them directly?

Comment: Roberto - correct. That was a typo.
Nick - The list of states to run is used for about 8 other routines and separate syntaxes, so it's easy to store them all in one place (an external file), so each routine can reference that single file.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop (nor a *macro*) to keep observations, as dictated by some "list" in another dataset. You can use `merge`:

```
clear
set more off

*----- example file with list of interest ----

sysuse auto
keep make
drop in 6/69

list

tempfile MakesToRun
save "`MakesToRun'"

*---- work with selected observations ----

clear
set more off

sysuse auto
keep make price mpg rep78

list

// keep observations that only appear in list of interest
merge 1:1 make using "`MakesToRun'", keep(matched)

list
```

Check `help merge` and the corresponding manual entry to get a good grasp of its working.

You can do this for multiple files using a loop.

Maybe there's a better way to setup the whole thing, but we don't have enough information.

Comment: The full code inside the loop is a few hundreds line long. The `keep if` command is just the first of *many* different commands that make use of the `MyState` value (like tempfile holding, save 'holding', opening another file, dropping the MyState, appending, replacing, etc. `MyState` is also used later for saving files with the state name (e.g., `save "... "Outcomes for `MyState'.dta."`), etc.